# Как работать с COM-объектами в java?

Tags: java

Добрый день.

1) дано COM - сервер с объектами.

2) описание того что каждый объект делает.

Посоветуйте как использовать (подключить) их в своём Java-коде ?

Пример. 
Есть интерфейс ISpRecordChannelClientW
у него есть метод Connect который устанавливает соединение с указанным каналом записи. Как его можно вызвать в своём java- коде скажем при нажатии кнопки подключиться.

Comment: Вам нужен какой-нибудь java-com bridge. Наиболее успешной и стабильной реализацией считаются [JACOB](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/) и [com4j](http://com4j.kohsuke.org).

Comment: К сожалению, помочь не смогу, сам с ним не работал.